# Is it possible to read the card number and expiration date from Sberbank and Tinkoff cards using NFC?

Tags: android

What is the problem with my code? I don't know if it's even possible to get the data I need in this way. If it can be done in some other way, you can tell me how. I need to read data from an NFC card and display it in a text field in Android Studio using Jetpack Compose. Here is my code:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SberbankCardDetails() {
   val context = LocalContext.current
   
   var cardNumber by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   var expirationDate by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
   
   val nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(context)
   
   val onTagDiscovered: (tag: Tag) -> Unit = { tag ->
      Log.e("TAG","tag:$tag")
      try {
         val isoDep = IsoDep.get(tag)
         isoDep.connect()

         // APDU for Sberbank
         val selectAidApdu = byteArrayOf(
            0x00, // CLA (Class)
            0xA4.toByte(), // INS (Instruction)
            0x04, // P1 (Parameter 1)
            0x00, // P2 (Parameter 2)
            0x0A, // Length of AID
            0xD4.toByte(), 0x40.toByte(), 0x06, 0x53.toByte(), 0x42.toByte(), 0x02.toByte()
         )

         // APDU to read card number
         val cardNumberApdu = byteArrayOf(
            0x00.toByte(), // CLA (Class)
            0x20.toByte(), // INS (Instruction)
            0x00.toByte(), // P1 (Parameter 1)
            0x00.toByte(), // P2 (Parameter 2)
            0x08.toByte()  // Length of expected response
         )

         // APDU to read expiration date
         val expirationDateApdu = byteArrayOf(
            0x00.toByte(), // CLA (Class)
            0x30.toByte(), // INS (Instruction)
            0x00.toByte(), // P1 (Parameter 1)
            0x00.toByte(), // P2 (Parameter 2)
            0x05.toByte()  // Length of expected response
         )

         val selectResult = isoDep.transceive(selectAidApdu)
         val newData = String(selectResult, Charset.forName("UTF-8")).trim()
         Log.e("RESULT","selectResult:$newData")

         val cardNumberResult = isoDep.transceive(cardNumberApdu)
         cardNumber = String(cardNumberResult, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
         Log.e("RESULT","cardNumber:$cardNumber")

         val expirationDateResult = isoDep.transceive(expirationDateApdu)
         expirationDate = String(expirationDateResult, Charset.forName("UTF-8"))
         Log.e("RESULT","expirationDate:$expirationDate")

         isoDep.close()
      } catch (e: Exception) {
         Log.e("SberbankCardDetails", "Error communicating with Sberbank card: ${e.message}")
      }
   }
   
   DisposableEffect(nfcAdapter) {
      val nfcCallback = object : NfcAdapter.ReaderCallback {
         override fun onTagDiscovered(tag: Tag?) {
            if (tag != null) {
               onTagDiscovered(tag)
            }
         }
      }
      nfcAdapter.enableReaderMode(
         context as Activity,
         nfcCallback,
         NfcAdapter.FLAG_READER_NFC_A,
         null
      )
      
      onDispose {
         nfcAdapter.disableReaderMode(context as Activity)
      }
   }
   
   Column(
      modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
   ) {
      Text("Card number: `$cardNumber`")
      Text("Expiration date: `$expirationDate`")
   }
}
```

After running the application and scanning the card, I receive the following output:

```java
E/TAG: tag:TAG: Tech [android.nfc.tech.IsoDep, android.nfc.tech.NfcA]
E/ISO_DEP: isoDep:android.nfc.tech.IsoDep@8105e47
E/RESULT: selectResult:g��
E/RESULT: cardNumber:m��
E/RESULT: expirationDate:m��
```

Changing the encoding did not help.